# Port forwarding - между двумя linux системами

Tags: linux, сеть

Не пойму как настроить Проброс и перенаправление портов средствами `iptables` или другими средствами.

Есть первая линукс машина, с `eth0` и `eth1`

`eth1` соединен с основной сетью:

```
ip-adress 192.168.0.155
subnet 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns 192.168.0.1
```

как я понял, `eth0` должен быть конфигурирован следующем образом:

```
ip-adress 192.168.2.155
subnet 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.155
dns 192.168.2.1
```

---

Вторая линукс машина 
`eth0`

```
ip-adress 192.168.2.160
subnet 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
dns 192.168.2.1
```

---

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward = 0
```

Таким образом у нас должно получится, что первая машина имеет соединение с основной сетью и на нее можно попасть через ип адрес `192.168.0.155`. Также, она предоставляет через `eth0` выход в интернет другой машине. Ко всему прочему, у нас должен будет быть способ попасть на вторую линукс машину из основной сети.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что SO по программированию. Есть другие SO для администрирование как http://askubuntu.com/ или http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Saidolim системное администрирование - ontopic на ruSO - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Saidolim они англоязычные. В русскоязычном сегменте ruSO вполне подходит для таких вопросов

Comment: Я откатил закрытие. Спасибо за комменты.

Comment: @Saidolim большое спасибо.


Теперь по самому вопрос, я так понимаю, нужно построить мост?

Comment: попробуйте `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` так как значение должно быть 1 как я понял для того что бы forwarding работал. И еще, какой Linux?

Comment: @Saidolim сейчас настройки выглядят вот так - http://pastebin.com/mCbRw1eV

armDebian

Comment: [микро-инструкция](http://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=103646), написанная шесть лет назад, но до сих пор не утратившая актуальности.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а как-же тогда разная подсеть?

Comment: @Insider, а что с ней не так?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну как я уже сказал, одна сетевая настроена под 192.168.0.1 другая под 192.168.2.1; Вторая машина под адресом - 192.168.2.167 даже пинговатся не будет

Comment: будет, конечно. при двух условиях: 1. icmp-пакеты не блокируются ни на одной из этих двух машин (или по пути между ними). 2. сеть физически функционирует.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin хм странно, но сеть все еще не работает

Comment: потому что интерфейс не поднят и не сконфигурирован.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. в приведённом [конфиге](http://pastebin.com/mCbRw1eV) как минимум отсутствует директива включения интерфейса *eth0*, и упоминания про шлюз и бридж — лишние (умолчальный шлюз должен быть один, и конфигурируется он с помощью *dhcp* при включении интерфейса *eth1*).

   приведите записи про конфигурацию *eth0* к такому виду:

   ```
   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.2.155
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   ```

   и «поднимите» интерфейс (после перезагрузки он будет «подниматься» автоматически):

   ```
   $ sudo ifup eth0
   ```
2. псевдо-файл `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` должен содержать `1` для того, чтобы пакеты могли перемещаться между интерфейсами внутри машины:

   ```
   $ echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   ```

   чтобы эта настройка сохранилась после перезагрузки, раскомментируйте (или добавьте, если не найдёте) в файле `/etc/sysctl.conf` строку:

   ```
   net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
   ```
3. ещё требуется правило в *netfilter* для преобразования адреса источника в пакетах, идущих из подключаемой сети в основную:

   ```
   $ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
   ```

   чтобы эта команда выполнялась при загрузке, можно, например, добавить её в файл `/etc/rc.local`:

   ```
   $ echo 'iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE' | sudo tee -a /etc/rc.local
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, это очень помогло и понятно написано. Теперь могу пинговать с машины которая передает интернет, а вот с ноутбука никак. Что нужно добавить?

Comment: что «пингуете»?

Comment: `ping 192.168.2.167` - этот IP адрес у меня установлен на второй машине.

Comment: заметил опечатку в предлагаемом правиле для netfilter-а: должен быть указан «внешний» интерфейс, в вашем случае — eth1. исправил ответ.

Comment: *этот IP адрес у меня установлен на второй машине* — увы, я не знаю, каким образом вы нумеруете машины. если это машина, подключенная к настраиваемому вами шлюзу, убедитесь, что ip-адрес и маска сети на ней соответствуют настройкам шлюза. // и не забывайте про [это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456766/#comment493988_456766)

Comment: Вторая машина это та, что только с одним eth0, на которую собственно мы раздаем интернет. Её настройки следующие `"ip": "192.168.2.167",
  "subnet": "255.255.255.0",
  "gateway": "192.168.2.1",
  "dns": "192.168.2.1",`

Comment: Как я понял, нужен ssh port forwarding на определенный порт. Скажем если я ввожу `ssh root@192.168.0.155 -p 88` меня переадресовывает на систему с одним `eth` на которую мы раздаем `xxx.xxx.2.xxx сеть`.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, должно работать вот так - `iptables -t nat -A FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0/24 --dport 88 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: *Если я не ошибаюсь, должно работать вот так* — если у вас дефолтные настройки netfilter-а (всё разрешено), то такое **разрешение** не требуется.

Comment: *Скажем если я ввожу* — извините, но ликбез по базовым принципам работы и маршрутизации в ip-сетях не уместится даже в рамки ответа. не говоря уж о комментариях. почитайте соответствующую литературу, пожалуйста.